# How to preload header logo image in WordPress? like what's the code and where do I put it?

Tags: php, functions, code

I want to preload image in header i.e. Logo, so what is the code for that and where do I put that logo?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try using `<link rel="preload" as="image" href="important.png">` but I don't think there is suppor for images preload outside of newer chrome versions

Comment: where do I add this code?

Comment: between the `<head>...</head>` tags, you can use hooks (that is the preferred way) but you can also add it directly in between those tags